# Row sums of dataframe with variable column indexes (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, sum, row

I have a dataframe that has a few million rows. I need to calculate the sum of each row from a particular column index up until the last column. The column index for each row is unique. An example of this, with the desired output, will be:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 2, 5, None, 4],
                   'col2': [4, 2, 4, 2, None, 1],
                   'col3': [6, 3, 8, 6, None, 4],
                   'col4': [9, 8, 9, 3, None, 5],
                   'col5': [1, 3, 0, 1, None, 7],
                   })

df_ind = pd.DataFrame({'ind': [1, 0, 3, 4, 3, 5]})

for i in df.index.to_list():
    df.loc[i, "total"] = df.loc[i][(df_ind.loc[i, "ind"]).astype(int):].sum()

print(df)

>>
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  total
0   1.0   4.0   6.0   9.0   1.0   20.0
1   2.0   2.0   3.0   8.0   3.0   18.0
2   2.0   4.0   8.0   9.0   0.0    9.0
3   5.0   2.0   6.0   3.0   1.0    1.0
4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    0.0
5   4.0   1.0   4.0   5.0   7.0    0.0
```

How can I achieve this efficiently with pandas without using a for loop. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a like-Indexed DataFrame that lists all of the column positions and then by comparing this DataFrame with `df_ind` you can create a mask for the entire original DataFrame.

Then `mask` the original DataFrame and `sum` to get the row sums based on the appropriate index positions that vary by row.

```
import pandas as pd

mask = pd.DataFrame({col: df.columns.get_loc(col) for col in df.columns}, 
                    index=df.index)
#   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
#0     0     1     2     3     4
#1     0     1     2     3     4
#2     0     1     2     3     4
#3     0     1     2     3     4
#4     0     1     2     3     4
#5     0     1     2     3     4

mask = mask.ge(df_ind['ind'], axis=0)
#    col1   col2   col3   col4   col5
#0  False   True   True   True   True
#1   True   True   True   True   True
#2  False  False  False   True   True
#3  False  False  False  False   True
#4  False  False  False   True   True
#5  False  False  False  False  False

df['total'] = df[mask].sum(1)
```

---

```
print(df)
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  total
0   1.0   4.0   6.0   9.0   1.0   20.0
1   2.0   2.0   3.0   8.0   3.0   18.0
2   2.0   4.0   8.0   9.0   0.0    9.0
3   5.0   2.0   6.0   3.0   1.0    1.0
4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    0.0
5   4.0   1.0   4.0   5.0   7.0    0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option, using numpy:

```py
cols = np.arange(len(df.columns))
# build a 2D array
mask = np.tile(cols, (len(df), 1))
# generate booleans by comparing to `df_ind`
mask = mask >= df_ind.to_numpy()
# replace True with `df`
mask = np.where(mask, df, mask)
# convert nulls to zero, and sum along the columns
mask = np.nan_to_num(mask).sum(1)
df.assign(total = mask)

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  total
0   1.0   4.0   6.0   9.0   1.0   20.0
1   2.0   2.0   3.0   8.0   3.0   18.0
2   2.0   4.0   8.0   9.0   0.0    9.0
3   5.0   2.0   6.0   3.0   1.0    1.0
4   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    0.0
5   4.0   1.0   4.0   5.0   7.0    0.0
```